# Sessão ficando aberta quando fecho o browser

Tags: javascript, jsf, session, http-request

Tenho um controle de usuário que armazena em uma AplicatioScope uma lista de usuários logados no sistema.
Junto com cada usuário, guardo o id da sessão que o mesmo esta logado.
Cada sessão dura em torno de 20 sem o usuário mexer no sistema.
Não permito o mesmo usuário com id da sessão diferente para evitar de conflito nas operações.
Se chamo a tela de login e já existe uma id logada no sistema, automaticamente recupero o usuário e redireciono para tela inicial do sistema. 
Se já existe um usuário logado com a id da sessão diferente, é feita uma pergunta se deseja derrubar a outra sessão do sistema.

Meu problema é que quando fecho o browser, a sessão continua aberta no sistema, e quando abro novamente o mesmo browser o id da sessão é alterado e identifica como se já tivesse um outro usuário logado no sistema.
Queria quando fechar o browser fazer logout no sistema.
Estava utilizando o comando *onbeforeunload* mas ele é acionado quando atualizo a tela e quando chamo uma nova tela.

Teria como verificar existe nenhum browser logado com a sessão (HttpSession) que está na lista da AplicationScope?

Ou talvez verificar se a aba ou o browser está realmente sendo fechado e não atualizado?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o modelo que você escolheu (uma sessão por usuário) gera um custo muito alto de controle para um valor muito pequeno de benefício. Você está basicamente lutando contra o paradigma da identidade multi-dispositivo.

Dada a própria natureza do protocolo HTTP e o comportamento dos browsers (onde uma conexão permanente ao servidor web não é garantida), eu tentaria outra abordagem: permita que um usuário possuia uma ou mais sessões. Mapeie suas operações por sessão, e não por usuário.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica... esse controle já esta funcionando bem... resolveu meu problema (de uma pessoa esta emitindo uma nfe e a outra abre a mesma nfe com o mesmo usuário e os dois tentar transmitir...)
Sendo que também já trato para duas ViewScope em abas diferentes, para validar as ações apenas da ultima view aberta. 
Posteriormente posso pensar em mapear as ações sim.
Mas se não fosse o detalhe de fechar o browser e mudar o id da sessão quando o mesmo for reaberto! A usabilidade ficou muito boa, simples e segura para o usuário. Valeu pela resposta...